# Cannot take partial snapshot of tkinter canvas properly

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, screenshot, tkinter-canvas

I've been following along a Python-Tkinter-Paint-App-Tutorial by [Codemy.com](https://codemy.com/), and everything worked fine up until the part where the app should take a screenshot of Only the Canvas part of the window and then save it as a PNG file. First all i got was complete black images, and now it only screenshots a small part of what it should.

I cannot link to the tutorial because it's a paid membership, but the instructor have a version of the source code on his [GitHub Account](https://github.com/flatplanet/Intro-To-TKinter-Youtube-Course/blob/master/painting.py). It's not exactly the same as he has been using throughout the tutorial, but almost.

When I've googled it, it seems to be an issue with the ImageGrab module, but I dont understand how and what to do.

The app works otherwise, and it DOES save a PNG, but Only like the top-left quarter of the canvas (and including part of the titlebar..). And when saving, I get the following Warning in my terminal:

'2021-06-25 03:24:03.306 python[4908:221427] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButton: 0x7f88d1f57b50>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.'

I'm on a macbook pro with OS big sur.
I scrolled through all comments on the course site and on [Codemys Youtube Account](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aZxW_iim80&t=63s) (which has a promotion video for this tutorial) looking for answers, and there seems to be a few others with the same issue. The instructors only tip (from what I've found) is to check the zoom settings, so Ive done that.
All dependencies seems to be installed and functioning properly.

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageTk, ImageGrab
import PIL
from tkinter import colorchooser
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title('Paint!')
root.geometry('800x800')

w = 600
h = 400
x = w/2
y = h/2

white = (255, 255, 255)
image1 = PIL.Image.new('RGB', (w, h), white)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image1)

my_canvas = Canvas(root, width=w, height=h, bg='#ffffff')
my_canvas.pack(pady=20)

# Default colors of brush and canvas
brush_color = 'black'
bg_color = 'white'


def paint(e):
    # Brush parameters
    brush_width = '%0.0f' % float(my_slider.get())
    # Brush Types/Cap Styles: BUTT, ROUND, PROJECTING
    brush_type2 = brush_type.get()
    # Starting position
    x1 = e.x - 1
    y1 = e.y - 1
    # Ending position
    x2 = e.x + 1
    y2 = e.y + 1
    # Draw on the canvas
    my_canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=brush_color, width=brush_width, capstyle=brush_type2, smooth=True)
    old_x = e.x
    old_y = e.y


def reset(event):
    old_x = None
    old_y = None


def save_as_png():
    result = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir='/Users/johfa/Pictures/Paintings', filetypes=(('png files', '*.png'), ('all files', '*.*')))
    if result.endswith('.png'):
        pass
    else:
        result = result + '.png'
    # result_label = Label(root, text=result)
    # result_label.pack(pady=20)
    if result:
        x=root.winfo_rootx()+my_canvas.winfo_x()
        y=root.winfo_rooty()+my_canvas.winfo_y()
        x1=x+my_canvas.winfo_width()
        y1=y+my_canvas.winfo_height()
        ImageGrab.grab().crop((x,y,x1,y1)).save(result)

        messagebox.showinfo('Image Saved', 'Your Image Has Been Saved!')


my_canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', paint)


def clear_screen():
    my_canvas.delete(ALL)
    my_canvas.config(bg='white')


def change_brush_color():
    global brush_color
    brush_color = 'black'
    brush_color = colorchooser.askcolor(color=brush_color)[1]
    # color = Label(root, text=brush_color)
    # color.pack(pady=20)


def change_canvas_color():
    global bg_color
    bg_color = 'white'
    bg_color = colorchooser.askcolor(color=bg_color)[1]
    my_canvas.config(bg=bg_color)


def change_brush_size(command_thing):
    slider_label.config(text='%0.0f' % float(my_slider.get()))



# Create brush options frame
brush_options_frame = Frame(root)
brush_options_frame.pack(pady=20)

# Brush size
brush_size_frame = LabelFrame(brush_options_frame, text='Brush Size')
brush_size_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=50)
# Brush slider
my_slider = ttk.Scale(brush_size_frame, from_=1, to=100, command=change_brush_size, orient=VERTICAL, value=10)
my_slider.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
# Brush slider label
slider_label = Label(brush_size_frame, text=my_slider.get())
slider_label.pack(pady=5)


# Brush type
brush_type_frame = LabelFrame(brush_options_frame, text='Brush Type', height=400)
brush_type_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=50)
# Create string variable for brush type to set and get
brush_type = StringVar()
brush_type.set('round')
# Create radio buttons for brush type
brush_type_radio1 = Radiobutton(brush_type_frame, text='Round', variable=brush_type, value='round')
brush_type_radio2 = Radiobutton(brush_type_frame, text='Slash', variable=brush_type, value='butt')
brush_type_radio3 = Radiobutton(brush_type_frame, text='Diamond', variable=brush_type, value='projecting')
# Put the radio buttons on the screen
brush_type_radio1.pack(anchor=W)
brush_type_radio2.pack(anchor=W)
brush_type_radio3.pack(anchor=W)


# Change color
change_colors_frame = LabelFrame(brush_options_frame, text='Change Color')
change_colors_frame.grid(row=0, column=2)
# Change brush color button
brush_color_button = Button(change_colors_frame, text='Brush Color', command=change_brush_color)
brush_color_button.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
# Change canvas color button
canvas_color_button = Button(change_colors_frame, text='Canvas Color', command=change_canvas_color)
canvas_color_button.pack(pady=10, padx=10)


# The program options frame
options_frame = LabelFrame(brush_options_frame, text='Options')
options_frame.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=50)

# Create clear button
clear_btn = Button(options_frame, text='Clear Screen', command=clear_screen)
clear_btn.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
# Create save image button
save_image_btn = Button(options_frame, text='Save as PNG', command=save_as_png)
save_image_btn.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

What am I not getting here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code works fine in my Windows 7 running Python 3.8.10. BTW, you can pass `(x,y,x1,y1)` to `ImageGrab.grab()` directly and then don't need to call `.crop()`.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author of the course? If you paid for it, it seems like you might be able to get some help that way.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try with that version!

Comment: I have written to him. No reply :(

Comment: You can refer to the following link:  https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3293
 
What is happening is- The Python Imaging Library uses a Cartesian pixel coordinate system. And, the internal mac screen capture ( cmd+shift+4 ), is not taking the pixel coordinate. 
So, you need to take the coordinate of the screen, and not the pixel coordinate.

Comment: Your code works absolutely fine for Windows.